# Count ways to make sum N

Tags: algorithm

For any non-negative integer K, suppose we have exactly two coins of value 2^K (i.e., two to the power of K).

Now we are given a long N. We need to find the number of different ways we can represent the value N with coins that we have.

(Two representations are considered different if there is a value that occurs a different number of times in the representations.)

Example : Let N=6 then answer is 3 as the following three representations are possible in this case:

```
{1, 1, 2, 2}
{1, 1, 4} and 
{2, 4}
```

How to do it if N can be upto 10^18?

Comment: I don't see how `N` and `K` are related. In the example you have obviously more than two coins (up to 4) and they all don't sum up to `N=3`. So what do you actually want to do?

Comment: Is there any relationship between `N` and `K`???There has to be some,else the question can't be solved!

Comment: @shekharsuman Relation in what sense?

Comment: @NicoSchertler In example if we first take K as 0 and 1 then we have first option.For K=0 and K=2 second one.And for K=1 and 2 third one

Comment: @NicoSchertler Also obviously K will have to satisfy that 2^k <N

Comment: @codetest-So how come `{1,1,4}` be a part of possible representations when `N=3`!

Comment: @shekharsuman Sorry..It was a typing error N is 6 here.

Comment: So you want to know how many possible solutions of the equation `N=m1*2^(2^k1) + m2*2^(2^k2)` exist for `k1>k2`? Is that accurate?

Comment: @NicoSchertler Yeah right..

Comment: @NicoSchertler-smart move!!! ha ha ha...

Comment: One possible solution would be to find all the numbers of the form `2^k<N` and try all the permutations whose sum would result to N. But,this is the trivial solution.Think along this direction!

Comment: This is a combinatorics problem, not a programming problem. Try http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

We can start with the trivial solution where we have one `2` and the rest `1`. This of course requires `N` to be at least 3. Otherwise, there is no solution:

```
coins1 = N - 2
coins2 = 1
nSolutions = 1
```

Let's first discuss the task of finding the number of possible merge operations of `M` equal coins where each and every coin must be merged (i.e. only a single coin type is used). This is the number of possible integer divisions of `M` by `2`. This procedure can cache intermediate results to perform subsequent calls faster (see dynamic programming).

But how is this useful? In the current state we can now subsequently exchange two `1's` for one `2`. This can be done until there are no more two `1's`, a total of `floor(N/2 - 1)` times. After each merge (actually after each second merge is sufficient), we have to check how often all `2's` can be merged. There are still `1's` in the state, so we can't use additional coin types:

```
while(coins1 >= 3)
{
    coins1 -= 2;
    coins2 += 1;
    nSolutions += 1;
    nSolutions += findNumberOfMerges(coins2); //this could be improved
}
```

If the `while` is left, there are either one or two `1's` left. If there is one left, we are done because this one must always be there and we have checked all possible combinations to represent the `2's` in a different way.

```
if(coins1 == 1)
    return nSolutions;
```

In the other case, we can merge once more. However, this will not result in a valid state because there is no second coin type. But we can merge once more to get a valid state (one `4` (becomes `coins2`) and the rest `2's` (becomes `coins1`)):

```
coins1 = coins2 + 1 - 2;
coins2 = 1;
nSolutions += 1;
```

Now we have a similar state as at the beginning, so we can run the whole procedure again. And again, and again until it returns.